# Cut a face with a pattern that goes off the face

Tags: faces, extrude

[image]

How do I cut these triangles in a face so that I can extrude them up individually by color

Comment: You might be better off starting with the color stairs, and then cut the rest of it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start with a plane, scaled a bit on one axis. Add a loop cut to the center (lengthwise) and translate the edge to one side to make kind of an arrow shape. Add loop cuts widthwise to make the sections for the "stairs":

[image: Stair1]

Add a cylinder (different object) and rotate it on the Z-Axis by 5.5 degrees, so the flat sides of the cylinder (instead of the "points") line up with the edges of the plane. As you can see from the image, the cylinder is slightly smaller than the plane - scale along the relevant axis until the edges line up.

[image: Stair2]

Move the whole cylinder to the "end" of your arrow plane, so that the flat sides of the cylinder line up with the beginning of the flat sides of the arrow. However, you can see from the image that a small section of the arrow point is protruding through the cylinder.

[image: Stair3]

Turn on *Proportional Editing* (<kbd>O</kbd>) and move the front face away until the whole arrow is inside the cylinder.

[image: Stair4]

Select the plane and add a Boolean Modifier set to *Intersect*. Choose the Cylinder as your boolean object.

[image: Stair5]

Apply the modifier. After it is applied, you can delete the "cutter" object.

[image: Stair6]

If you look at your mesh in Edit Mode, you will see that the boolean has left some stray vertices. Select and dissolve them:

[image: Stair7]

[image: Stair8]

You now have the base shape from which to extrude your stairs:

[image: Stair9]

Comment: Thanks man, I was having a hard time with this one, still learning blender :)
Coming from fusion 360 where I did this in 30 seconds really demotivated me

Comment: Glad it works for you. As with any 3D program, there are multiple ways of doing basically _everything_, and this is just _one_ of those ways.